# Should I Escape Single Quotes Before Sending a Value to a Parameterized Query?

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, adodb

I was told (or read somewhere) that when you use parameterized queries (e.g. with an `ADODB.Command` object), all of the escaping is handled internally either within the Command object or within the database engine.

Is this true?

An Example of my command code is below - is it safe to pass a raw parameter as with the first parameter created, or should it be escaped as with the second parameter?

My specific environment is vbscript on windows 2008 (or newer) and SQL Server 2008 (or newer).

```
Dim oSproc : Set oSproc = CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 
With oSproc
    .ActiveConnection = oConn
    .CommandText = "mysp_SPNAME"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 
    With .Parameters
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_str1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, myStr)
        .Append oSproc.CreateParameter("@IN_str2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, replace(myStr, "'", "''"))
    End With 
    .Execute 
End With
```

Comment: Why don't you just test it and see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its true; parametrization is done by the Command object when you use it in conjunction with Parameter objects.

You can verify this by passing `"'"` and observing there is no error, or by running a trace and looking at the sp_executeSQL call.